# Stored procedure class is not found in edmx model MVC-4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, edmx

Sorry if it's a duplicate, but I searched quite a lot and was unable to find a solution.

I have imported 4 stored procedures from the database into my `.edmx` model, but one among them is not populated properly so that I am unable to add the as reference on top of my view to assign the result to loop on that view.

I deleted all those procedures from model browser window from three directories and imported them again but the missing procedure doesn't appear under the "Complex Types" in Model browser screen.

Here is a screen showing methods under stored procedure/function in model browser:

[image]

Here is the image of screen under "Complex Types" showing only 3 procedures:

[image]

Following are the screenshots of the procedures with returning values:

[image]

[image]

Kindly help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee i just added some images to give you bit more explaination if you could understand what i am trying to explain.

Comment: Check the return types of sp's it could be like either they return a scalar value or same complex result set

Comment: they are returning the same complex types

Comment: thats why its showing 3 only

Comment: i am returning list of records from the procedure which is not appearing there

Comment: See if 2 sp has same return type list then they can share single class

Comment: sorry dint get your point bro. :(

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee just added the storedProcedure's screen shot with returned columns kindly have a look at them.

Comment: both images return type is int so it will not have a sclass its a scalar return type